# Does Mac OS X load average reporting (via top) include processes waiting on IO?

Tags: macos, performance

I'm looking at the output of top to view my system's load average.  I want to understand whether the load average is reporting processes just waiting for CPU, or whether it's reporting processes that are waiting for either CPU or IO.

[This article](http://linuxtechsupport.blogspot.com/2008/10/what-exactly-is-load-average.html) suggests that most unix systems report only CPU in their load, but that linux in particular reports both CPU and IO.

I'm guessing that OS X probably does not include IO in its load reporting, but I'd like to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, the kernel task accumulates IO wait time and the process accumulates CPU time managing the IO call setup and results but not the actual IO wait.

Put another way, in `top` or Activity Monitor, IO waiting is time when the CPU is idle. The system/kernel would take any core storage / filevault processing time needed to accomplish the IO but for the general case with a normal drive there isn't CPU overhead on IO past the normal virtual memory overhead.

Comment: that sounds like no?

Comment: Right. Waiting on I/O doesn't consume CPU time.